# Table has more columns then showing in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a table on live DB named as `iavlif_menu`.

[image]

When exporting the table sql query has less number of columns then the actual one.

Here is the `sql query`.

```
--
-- Table structure for table `iavlif_menu`
--

CREATE TABLE `iavlif_menu` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `menutype` varchar(24) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The type of menu this item belongs to. FK to #__menu_types.menutype',
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The display title of the menu item.',
  `alias` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'The SEF alias of the menu item.',
  `note` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `path` varchar(1024) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The computed path of the menu item based on the alias field.',
  `link` varchar(1024) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The actually link the menu item refers to.',
  `type` varchar(16) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The type of link: Component, URL, Alias, Separator',
  `published` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT AS `The published state of the menu link.`,
  `parent_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' AS `COMMENT`
) ;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `iavlif_menu`
--
ALTER TABLE `iavlif_menu`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

**EDIT**

We have only one `DB`

[image]

As per @Axalix command `desc iavlif_menu;`. I am getting all the columns

How it is happening and how it can be solved?

Comment: It is probably because another database is selected.

Comment: @Axalix : how it can be possible?

Comment: When you have 2 tabs in the browser opened and changed a DB in a second tab, for example. Just close all phpmyadmin windows and tabs, open one, relogin and try again.

Comment: @Axalix : no, I have only one tab in my whole browser and I am exporting the same.

Comment: I didn't vote on this. But you can't expect explanations on something that doesn't make any sense. You should double check DB name everywhere and try again (may be in a different browser).

Comment: there is only one DB. check the updated question.

Comment: Try `desc iavlif_menu;` command. What does it return?

Comment: it return all the columns